# PostgreSQL: what's the difference between "alter table ... add unique (...)" and "alter table ... add constraint ... unique (...)"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique, alter-table

According to tests both SQL give the same result.

```sql
alter table public.company add constraint company_name_key unique ("name")
```

vs.

```sql
alter table public.company add unique ("name");
```

PostgreSQL (ver. 12.16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard ISO SQL language admit those two syntaxes. In the first one you choose the name of the contraint while the second one will generate a name for the constraint by an internal RDBMS process.

When altering/droping a constraint you need to give the name of the constraint.
It is why I will advocate the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, because you decided to use the same constraint name that PostgreSQL uses by default. The error message will be

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "company_name_key"
```

in both cases. You'll use the version where you can decide for a name, when you want a different name, say every constraint name starting with c_.

When working with large databases with many tables and a lot of hierarchie, table names may become very long and column names, too, in order to be descriptive. Let's say you have a table named `customer_order_item_customs_tariff` with a column called `customs_tariff_document_number`. PostgreSQL will call your constraint

```
customer_order_item_customs_t_customs_tariff_document_numbe_key
```

but maybe you prefer something like

```
c_corderitemtariff_docno
```

In my opinion PostgreSQL does a very good job here. I like the automatically generated names. But if you don't, use the verbose version of `ALTER TABLE` to add a unique constraint matching your naming conventions or likes.